# Adding buy it now and add to cart button with only 1 drop down

Tags: php, html, forms, e-commerce

I want to add a buy it now button and add to cart button on the same form with only 1 drop down menu. At present I have 2 drop down menus which are exactly the same if I want to have the buy it now and add to cart button.

So basically I want to use only 1 drop down menu for the buy it now and add to cart button which link into both buttons.

Here is the html for buy it now button only.

```
<form id="form_35" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_self" style="margin:0;position:absolute;left:492px;top:112px;width:199px;height:68px; /*MainDivStyle*/" __AddCode="here">
    <!--MainDivStart-->
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Serif.WebPlus">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@mysite.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Polo Shirt">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="0.18">
    <input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="kgs">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Special Instructions">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" >
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Colour">



    <!-- Combo Box combo_30 -->

    <!--Preamble-->
    <select name="os0" size="1" style="position:absolute; left:8px; top:8px; /*Tag Style*/" __AddCode="here">
        <option value="Black" __AddCode="here">Black</option>
        <option value="White" __AddCode="here">White</option>
    </select>
    <!--Postamble-->


    <!-- Button btn_29 -->

    <!--Preamble-->
    <div style="position:absolute;left:75px;top:2px;width:116px;height:28px;"><button type="submit" id="btn_29" class="Button4" style="width:116px;height:28px;"><span>Buy&nbsp;Now</span></button></div>
    <!--Postamble-->
    </form>
    <!--Postamble-->
<!--MainDivEnd-->
</div>
```

ADD TO CART FROM:

```
<form id="form_36" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_self" style="margin:0;position:absolute;left:647px;top:957px;width:271px;height:44px; /*MainDivStyle*/" __AddCode="here">
<!--MainDivStart-->
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Serif.WebPlus">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Polo Shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20.00">
<input type="hidden" name="weight" value="0.18">
<input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="kgs">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Colour">


<!-- Combo Box combo_31 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<select name="os0" size="1" style="position:absolute; left:8px; top:8px; /*Tag Style*/" __AddCode="here">
    <option value="Black" __AddCode="here">Black</option>
    <option value="White" __AddCode="here">White</option>
</select>
<!--Postamble-->


<!-- Button btn_24 -->

<!--Preamble-->
<div style="position:absolute;left:75px;top:0px;width:188px;height:36px;"><button type="submit" id="btn_24" class="Button5" style="width:188px;height:36px;"><span>Add&nbsp;to&nbsp;Cart</span></button></div>
<!--Postamble-->
</form>
```

Hopefully the picture will give more insight into what I would like to do.

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/3108/buttonvb.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the fields are similar in both forms, so I suggest to keep the first form **only**, remove the second form, put both buttons in the first form and use `javascript` to switch between commands:

Changes in first form:

Add another hidden field (required for cart option)

```
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
```

Add **onclick** event on both buttons

```
<button type="submit" id="btn_29" class="Button4" style="width:116px;height:28px;" onclick="setCMD('_xclick');"><span>Buy&nbsp;Now</span></button>
<button type="submit" id="btn_24" class="Button5" style="width:188px;height:36px;" onclick="setCMD('_cart');"><span>Add&nbsp;to&nbsp;Cart</span></
```

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCMD(cmd) {
    form = document.getElementById("form_35");
    form.cmd.value = cmd; 
}   
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for you help. What is happening now is that both button (buy it now and add to cart) are adding the item to cart. So the add to cart button is working but the buy it now is not. http://pastebin.com/c2Myhczf

Comment: it's working fine with me. I also tried to copy the code in the link you provided and added the javascript function and it worked! http://pastebin.com/7bkhtQNZ

Comment: which browser you are using?